# Upvote function using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm new to programming. I'm creating an upvote and downvote function using ajax. I want to display the count for the class "vote-count". By default, the vote-count is 0. which ajax function should i use to change the count value when I click the upvote button?

```
<label class="q-list-left question-vote-up" question-id="<?=$questionId?>">
       <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</label>
<label class="q-list-left vote-count" style="text-align: center;"question-id="<?=$questionId?>"><?=$vote?>
</label>
<label class="q-list-left question-vote-down" question-id="<?=$questionId?>">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</label>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.question-vote-up',function() {
        //alert("test");
        var questionId      =   $(this).attr('question-id');
        var link_url            =   base_url+"question";
        var post_data           =   [{name:'AJAX',value:'AJAX'},
        {name:'TYPE',value:'ACTION'},
        {name:'ACTION',value:'QUESTION_UPVOTE'},
        {name:'QUESTION_ID',value:questionId}
        ];


        $.ajax({

            url:link_url,
            dataType    : "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: post_data,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.STATUS  == 200) {
                    var vote        =   $(questionId+"question-id"+'').text();  //here I'm trying to implement the vote count.
                    $(questionId+"question-id"+'').text(parseInt(vote + 1));
                    
                    //alert(response.MESSAGE);
                } else if(response.STATUS   == 400) {
                    alert(response.MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    alert(response.MESSAGE);
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error in response");
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: where is your error/issue now?

Comment: One thing is that you **cannot** create ``custom attributes`` without the use of ``data-``. So yours ``question-id="<?=$questionId?>"`` is invalid.  You can use ``data-question-id="<?=$questionId?>"``, if you need any custom attribute(question-id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using "question-id" attribute as selector in wrong way. Try this instead:

```
if(response.STATUS  == 200) {
  var countLabel = $('label[question-id="'+questionId+'"]');
  var vote  =   countLabel.text();  //here I'm trying to implement the vote count.
  countLabel.text(parseInt(countLabel.text() + 1));
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to target a specific label upvote, downvote, favorite like in your case then you can do using the element class or id. Like this: `label.vote-count`

```
var countLabel = $('label.vote-count[question-id="'+questionId+'"]');
```

Comment: Thanks! this worked.....but i have using questionId in different places like in upvote and downvote, favorite icon, so on. All these are getting updated with the count

Comment: @NajadRiyaz Check now. I have updated my answer according to your needs.

Comment: thanks, man...you saved my time...really appreciate your help...and also have one more doubt...if you can help, it would be great to me....currently, the upvote count is incrementing in every click...but it should be upvoted only once for a user...how can we do like that?

Comment: @NajadRiyaz Glad to hear that it. Please upvote and accept the answer. Also, I suggest you to post a separate question for your other problem with proper explanation and code.